# i can not get bash For loops to work, anything after do becomes an unexpected token

Tags: bash, for-loop

for some reason this:

```
#!/bin/bash
for ln in {1 2 3}; do
done
exit 0
```

produces the following error:

./Untitled-1.sh: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `done' ./Untitled-1.sh: line 3:` done'

can anyone tell me what i am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do something in the loop. E.g.

```
echo "$ln"
```

That will also show you that the brace expansion doesn't use spaces to separate elements.

The correct syntax would be

```bash
for ln in 1 2 3 ; do
# or
for ln in {1,2,3} ; do
```